# Hints on proving $\liminf_{s\to 0}\sup_{f\in L^2(X):||f||_{L^2}\leq 1}\int_X|f(x)|^2|e^{-is/||x||}-1|^2dx>0$ for $X=\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, lp-spaces, limsup-and-liminf

Take $X = \mathbb{R}^n$, denote by $\|x\|$ the standard Euclidean norm and consider the space of $L^2$ functions over $X$ in the Lebesgue measure. I am trying to show that the sequence $$I_s:=\sup_{f\in L^2(X):\|f\|_{L^2}\leq 1}\int_X|f(x)|^2|e^{-is/\|x\|}-1|^2\,\mathrm dx$$ does not converge to zero as $s\to 0$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit $i^2 = -1$. That is, I would like to conclude that e.g.
$$
\liminf_{s\to 0} \sup_{f\in L^2(X):\|f\|_{L^2} \leq 1}\int_X|f(x)|^2|e^{-is/\|x\|}-1|^2\,\mathrm dx>0$$

Failure of $I_s$ to converge to zero must happen around the origin, but so far I have not been able to either find some suitable $L^2$ function with which $I_s = \text{constant $C > 0$}$ for all $s > 0$ or deduce some identity of the norm $|e^{-is/\|x\|}-1|^2$ which would make this proof easier. Namely, as $|e^{-is/\|x\|}-1|^2 = 2(1 - \cos(s/\|x\|))$, it is quite hard to try to integrate the function over some neighbourhood $B(0,r)$, $r>0$. How should I try to approach this problem?

Comment: Take $f$ that concentrates around $|x| = s/\pi$ (for example a sequence of normalized gaussians), or use duality ; )

Comment: @LL3.14 I am not sure what you mean by duality, but I think I got the problem now!